# asp .net out of memory problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 private void GenerateThumbnails(double scaleFactor, string sourcePath,
 string targetPath) {
             int wi = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["dim2"]);
             int hi = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["dim1"]);
             using (var image =
 System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(sourcePath))
             {
                 var newWidth = (int)(wi);//(image.Width *
 scaleFactor);
                 var newHeight = (int)(hi);// (image.Height *
 scaleFactor);
                 var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                 var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
                 thumbGraph.CompositingQuality =
 CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                 thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                 thumbGraph.InterpolationMode =
 InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                 var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth,
newHeight);
                 thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
                 int getwal = newWidth - 108;
                 int gethi = newHeight - 30;
                 SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(113,
 255, 255, 255));
                 thumbGraph.DrawString("myfile", new Font("Arial", 12,
 System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), brush, getwal,gethi);
                 thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);
             } }
```

hi i am getting error while uploading pics

i get the error of

Out of memory.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
 the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
 trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
 the code.

```
Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.

 Source Error: 


 Line 177:            thumbGraph.InterpolationMode =
 InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; Line 178:            var
 imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight); Line 179:  
 thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle); Line 180:           
 thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);
```

Comment: What does GenerateThumbnails() have to do with 'while uploading pics' ?

Comment: Wait a minute, this is an asp.net application and you are loading the image from file doing Image.FromFile? Are you aware that you are reading the file from the Server's file system and not the client's? Further, are you aware that in order to read it from the server you probably need to do Server.MapPath? That may or may not be the cause of the error.

Comment: The good news is that the Image class complains with OutOfMemory for just about anything, so it's probably something else. Like a wrong path or a Size calculation going wrong. Use a Debugger.

Comment: What are the image dimensions here, might be they are too large and causing the memory overrun

Answer (score 0):

Try switching from the built-in debugger or IISExpress to full-blown local IIS for testing.  Often times there are some limitations (especially with IIS Express) that don't expose themselves in the same way with the different environments.

If that doesn't immediately resolve your problem, your best bet is to either use the memory profiling tools built into VS 2010, or to download and use a trial of the RedGate ANTS Profiler.